# Проблема с MeasureString ()

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с проблемой, что строчка

```cs
graphics.MeasureString (text.Replace ("\n", "\r\n"), richTextBox1.Font, new Size (354, 0))
```

Возвращает неверный размер. Иногда размер больше на 5, а иногда на 120, в зависимости от размера строки. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Оно и должно работать `в зависимости от размера строки.`

Comment: @tym32167, чем больше строка, тем больше лишних пикселей в размере. Например, у меня есть текст, который помещается в текстбоксе с высотой 560, но MeasureString вернёт 700. Или же вместо 25 он вернёт 27. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте [эту перегрузку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_MeasureString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_SizeF_System_Drawing_StringFormat_System_Int32__System_Int32__) использовать. В ней почти все параметры строки можно настроить, включая всякие отступы/выступы

Comment: @rdorn особенных StringFormat у меня вроде нет, а больше там нечего указывать.